# Finding controls in repeater on commandargument

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Items" OnItemCommand="rpt_Items_ItemCommand" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="fr">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_amount" runat="server">1</asp:TextBox>
                        <p>
                            <%# Eval("itemPrice") %>
                        </p>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_buy" CommandName="buy" runat="server">buy</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_ID" Value='<%# Eval("itemID") %>' runat="server" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

On the repeater commandargument i want to get the textbox and the hiddenfield but how do i do this?

```
protected void rpt_Items_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "buy")
    {
        //ADD ITEM TO CART
        Response.Write("ADDED");


        Product getProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == id);
        if (getProduct != null)
        {
            CartProduct product = new CartProduct()
            {
                Name = getProduct.ProductName,
                Number = amount,
                CurrentPrice = getProduct.ProductPrice,
                TotalPrice = amount * getProduct.ProductPrice,
            };
            cart.AddToCart(product);
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to pass it through the Command Argument, you can use `e.Item.FindControl()` inside your `rpt_Items_ItemCommand` method, as in:

```
TextBox tb_amount = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tb_amount");
HiddenField hdn_ID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdn_ID");
```